# Etymology and usage of "freuen" and "froh"?

Tags: etymology

Is there an etymological connection between these two words that share a similar meaning?
And also, do they share the same meaning?

Comment: What did your research show?

Comment: Ja, *freuen*, *Freude*, *froh* haben gemeinsamen Ursprung: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=Adelung&lemid=DF02610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They share a common origin as said in the comments. However, *freuen* is a verb, *froh* is an adjective.

Also the meanings are slightly different:

> Ich freue mich über .../Ich freue mich auf ...
>   I am happy ... /I'm looking forward to ...

whereas

> Ich bin froh
>   I am glad

Answer (score 2):

Yes they share the same meaning, but both words are used differently:

```
Ich freue mich, dass die Sonne scheint.
```

or

```
Ich bin froh, dass die Sonne scheint.
```

Just because nobody mentioned it: 'freuen' is a verb and 'froh' an adjective.

And no, it's raining :(

Comment: I did mention it and no, the meaning is not exactly the same! *froh sein* is different from *sich freuen*. :-)

Comment: Yes, you where faster ;)
And yes, its 'slightly different' but 'they share the same meaning' like 'glad' and 'happy' do ;)